# XMLNode with more values and same name

Tags: delphi, txmldocument

I must create xml document with node that has more values with same name

```
<PstlAdr>
  <Ctry>SI</Ctry>
  <AdrLine>Gosposvetska 12</AdrLine>
  <AdrLine>Kranj</AdrLine>
</PstlAdr>
```

With `oNode.ChildValues['AdrLine'] := ...` it is not possible - only one value with same name can be added. How can I add more values with same name?

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
oNode.AddChild('AdrLine').Text := ...
```